# Decrypting a message encrypted using a hashed key

Tags: java, encryption

I have a problem where I need to decrypt a message which was encrypted using AES=256. I am already provided with a key and vector. I have to hash the provided key using SHA-256 and then use this hash to encrypt a message. The decryption code runs fine but the result is not the original `String`.
Result: `?m?>? ???????z?p???>??<3?` (the exact text is different, but after copying and pasting it, it is different).

My code below:

```
try {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] hashBytes = digest.digest("someKey".getBytes(ENCODING_UTF8)); 
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("somevector".getBytes(ENCODING_UTF8));
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(hashBytes, AES);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(ENCODING_UTF8));          
    encrypted = EACECryptoUtils.base64Encode(cipherText);
    Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION_TYPE);
    IvParameterSpec decryptIV = new IvParameterSpec("somevector".getBytes(ENCODING_UTF8));
    SecretKeySpec decryptSkeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(hashBytes, AES);
    decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, decryptSkeySpec, decryptIV);
    byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(EACECryptoUtils.base64Decode(encrypted));
    decrypted = new String(original);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(new LogRecord(FUNCTION_NAME + "Exception while encrypting the data", e));
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you read your question once more and clarify please?

Comment: what is the TRANSFORMATION_TYPE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(EACECryptoUtils.

I believe you should use `decryptCipher` instead of `cipher`

Comment: That worked. Really embarrassed for making such a silly mistake, and then posting as well..Thanks for your time!!!
On other note, do you think it is a wise idea to hash the key and then encrypt?

Comment: @AbhinashJha assumimg the password is having high entropy (is long and random) it is ok. If the password humand entered, you may rather use PBKDF to generate a key from the password. And IV should be random for CBC mode

Comment: Thanks @gusto2. I am using a random password and not human entered. I have another question, if you may please answer. I am trying the above code in JRE1.6 , and it gives Illegal Key size. I have done some research, and I think we need to download JCE jars(local_policy.jar, US_export_policy.jar). But is there a way around to this?

Comment: @AbhinashJha For Java1.6 you need the JCE export policy. I believe OpenJDK 8 may already allow crypto without restrictions (I may be wrong). Another option is using AES-128 (128 bit key) it is secure enough

Comment: as per our requirement we need to use AES-256. I see that from Java 1.7, the above code is working fine. But , if I replace the below
 SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(hashBytes, AES);
with
 SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("someKey".getBytes(ENCODING_UTF8), AES);
where "someKey" is the provided key.
the encryption and decryption is working fine in Java 1.6 as well. It only fails when I hash the provided key and then encrypt against this hash key. SO, this is confusing for me. Do you have some idea on this issue?

Comment: any comments please

Comment: @AbhinashJha+ _all_ versions of OpenJDK (since it started in late 6) are free of the 128-bit-key 'export' restriction. _Sun/Oracle_ has the restriction (and thus needs a patch) through 7, and in 8 _below_ update 161, but not not in 9 and 10 (and soon 11). This has been asked and answered many times over the past years; please consider looking at existing Qs. If you use `"somekey".getBytes(UTF8)` as an AES key it fails; if you actually use some other string you won't tell us, look at the `.length` of the `byte[]` returned from `getBytes(encoding)`. And Stack is NOT for discussion.